# Reading a file stored in hdfs in Airflow DAG python file

Tags: airflow

I am new to Airflow and Python. I want to read a file from HDFS inside Airflow PythonOperator.
I want to read this file inside dag.py file(python file containing the DAG info).

However, I do not understand that how to add **dependencies of hdfs or rather any other dependency** and read inside the dag.py file.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, i am using bashoperator to call the python file and reading the contents from HDFS

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': days_ago(1)
    }

# Defining the DAG using Context Manager
with DAG(
        'bash_write',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=None,
        ) as dag:


        create_operator = BashOperator(
                task_id = 'create_task',
                bash_command = 'python /usr/local/airflow/dags/source.py',
        )
  create_operator
```

python script:

```py
import os
s=os.system("hdfs dfs -cat /home/xxx/testing/input")
print(s)
```